# Django Query where one field is duplicate and another is different

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to know if I can create a query where one field is duplicate and another one is different.

Basically I want to get all UsersNames where `First Name` is the same and `user_id` is different.
I did this

```
UserNames.objects.values("first_name", "user_id").annotate(ct=Count("first_name")).filter(ct__gt=0)
```

This will retrieve a list whit all Users

After tis, I make some post processing and create another query where I filter just the users with `first_name__in=['aaa'] & user_id__in=[1, 2]` to get the users with the same `first_name` but different `user_id`

Can I do this just in one query? or in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a subquery here, but it will not matter much in terms of performance I think:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

UserNames.objects.filter(
    Exists(UserNames.objects.filter(
        ~Q(user_id=OuterRef('user_id')),
        first_name=OuterRef('first_name')
    ))
)
```

or prior to [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

UserNames.objects.annotate(
    has_other=Exists(UserNames.objects.filter(
        ~Q(user_id=OuterRef('user_id')),
        first_name=OuterRef('first_name')
    ))
).filter(has_other=True)
```

We thus retain `UserNames` objects for which there exists a `UserNames` object with the same `first_name`, and with a different `user_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I use django 1.11.2,  and I get the Error `'Exists' object is not iterable`

Comment: @jalanga: then you need to use the second approach. The `Exists` in a `.filter(..)` only works since Django-3.0.