# Django ORM: how do I count objects that have the same properties?

Tags: django

I want to use the Django ORM to find instances in my models that have some of the same properties.

For instance, given this model:

```
class Person(Model):
  name = CharField()
  age = IntegerField()
  gender = CharField()
```

how can I find all persons that don't have a unique age and gender?

For instance given the following data:

```
 John 20 M
  Bob 21 M
Diana 20 F
Janet 20 F
```

I want a query that would return Diana and Janet.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: this seems to be a duplicate of [Django Query where one field is duplicate and another is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393772/django-query-where-one-field-is-duplicate-and-another-is-different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a subquery and filter such that there is at least one other `Person` with the same name:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Person.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        Person.objects.exclude(
            pk=OuterRef('pk')
        ).filter(age=OuterRef('age'), gender=OuterRef('gender'))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this supposed to work on Django 1.11? I get `TypeError: 'Exists' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene From Django 3.0 onwards one can directly filter on `Exists`, for versions before that you need to `annotate` it first and filter on that. **Note**: Django 1.11 is an insecure version of Django that is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a newer release!

Comment: Thanks, found it here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393772/django-query-where-one-field-is-duplicate-and-another-is-different